# If $P(A) = P(B) = P(A\cup B)$, prove that $P((A \cap B^{c}) \cup (B\cap A^{c})) = 0$

Tags: probability

This is a question from one of exams in my school in previous years. The question is described in the title.

I have tried to work it out this far (I skipped some intermediate steps for simplification's sake):

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
P(A\cap B^{c})=P(A)+P(B^{c})-P(A\cup B^{c})=1-P(A\cup B^{c})\\\\
P((B \cap A^{c})=1-P((B \cup  A^{c})
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
P((A \cap B^{c}) \cup (B\cap A^{c}))=2-P(A\cup B^{c})-P((B \cup  A^{c})-P((A \cap B^{c}) \cap (B\cap A^{c}))
\end{align*}

This is as far as I can get.

The reason is because I tried to expand the terms, hoping to find way to simplify the results, but the expressions are getting longer and longer.

Please advise how I should proceed with the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma**

Given $X$ and $Y$ events of the sample space $\Omega$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(X) & = \textbf{P}(X\cap Y) + \textbf{P}(X\cap Y^{c})\\\\
\end{align*}

**Proof**

It suffices to note that $X = X\cap\Omega = X\cap(Y\cup Y^{c}) = (X\cap Y)\cup(X\cap Y^{c})$.

**Solution**

Based on the given assumption, we have that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cup B) & = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B)\\\\
& = 2\textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) = \textbf{P}(A)\\\\
& \Rightarrow \textbf{P}(A) = \textbf{P}(B) = \textbf{P}(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

Since the events $A\cap B^{c}$ and $B\cap A^{c}$ are mutually exclusive, one has that
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}((A\cap B^{c})\cup(B\cap A^{c})) & = \textbf{P}(A\cap B^{c}) + \textbf{P}(B\cap A^{c})\\\\
& = \textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B) =0
\end{align*}

and we are done.